# Position:absolute with height is not responsive

Tags: css, position, response, absolute

I have a container: Width 950px + 25px padding on left and right site. If the browser windows i under 1000px, the container adjust the width to 94% + 3% padding on both sites.

On the top, there is a Div with 4 images with a slideshow (only one image at the same time). The Div with the slideshow shall have the full width from the whole container (width+padding).

My problem is, that this solution is not responsive. Because of the "position: absolute" I have also a fixed height of 556px. Otherwise the content is under the Slideshow-Div. But if I open the website with my smartphone, the 556px are too high for a mobile screen. Now, I'm not knowing how to solve the responsive problem. I think I need the "position: absolute" to overcome the padding on my Container. What can I do?

```css
#cycler {
  position: relative;
  height: 556px;
}
#cycler img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 1000px !important;
  margin-top: -33px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
#cycler img.active {
  z-index: 3
}
```

```html
<div id="cycler">
  <img src="/images/startseite-familie.jpg" style="" class="active">
  <img src="/images/startseite-familie-mit-kind.jpg" style="">
  <img src="/images/startseite-alleinerziehende-mutter.jpg" style="">
  <img src="/images/startseite-geschwister.jpg" style="">
</div>
```

Comment: could you post a fiddle / link to your page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just from looking at your code above, I've adjusted your css to fit.

You'll have to adjust the padding-bottom to fit your images, but this should work for you.

```css
#cycler {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  /* 
   * REPLACE HEIGHT WITH PADDING BOTTOM %, 
   * WHICH WORKS FROM THE SCREEN WIDTH 
   * THIS MAKING THE HEIGHT RESPONSIVE
   **/
  padding-bottom: 40%;
}
#cycler img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /*
   * SET THE MAX-WIDTH TO 100% 
   * WHICH WILL ONLY FILL THE CURRENT CONTAINER
   **/
  max-width: 100% !important;
  margin-top: -33px;
  margin-left: -25px;
}
#cycler img.active {
  z-index: 3
}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you so simple, jeese. Amazing what we overlook.